# Using vi keybindings for readline, how do I go to the start of line?

Tags: bash, vi, readline

In a multiline command, there is a difference between

- Start of the line
- Start of the command

using the vim keybindings `set -o vi` **FOR READLINE (ex., bash, psql etc)**, how do I go to the start of the line and not the start of the command.

**This question is not on VIM. It's on the vi keybinidngs for readline applications**.

Copy this... all of it (the multiline block quote below)

> In a multiline command, there is a difference between
>
> - Start of the line
> - Start of the command
>
> using the vim keybindings `set -o vi`, how do I go to the start of the line and not the start of the command.

Now follow these instructions..

1. Type `echo "`
2. Paste the above.
3. Type `"` to finish the command and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Now press the up-arrow to get that into the command buffer.

1. How do you now go to the start and end of a line, **not the command**?
2. How do you go up a line in a multi-line command, **not to a different command**?

Comment: Bash does not have “vim” key bindings, it has vi-like key bindings. Don't expect any of the Vim extensions to Vi and don't expect perfect compatibility even with basic Vi.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that this does *exactly* what you're asking for, but I suspect that it may be the closest thing that you're going to get.

<kbd>esc</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>

Will open the current command in your editor of choice (e.g. `$EDITOR`, or the editor set in `/etc/alternatives` in debian). Presumably, you'll have this set to vi or vim, and you can navigate from line to line using <kbd>j</kbd>, <kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>0</kbd>, <kbd>$</kbd> etc.

As a bonus,

```
shopt -s lithist
```

will keep the formatting of lines in history, rather than concatenating commands separated by semi-colons.

As noted by Evan Carroll, this only works for bash, but a lot of other programs that use readline also have external editors... e.g. `psql` allows command editing using `\e`.

Comment: <kbd>v</kbd> only works in bash (for me), but it's still a workaround for bash. It doesn't work in the rest of readline apps. Yet, this is still some kind of limited work around, I'll grant you.

Answer (score 1):

bash simply doesn't do what's requested: it sticks fairly close to ksh's imitation of **vi**.  The feature requested here is not a **vi** feature, but an extension provided by vim.

Comment: I don't think it's an extension provided by vim. I think it's a feature of readline and that it has nothing to do with bash.

Answer (score 1):

> - Start of the line
> - Start of the command

It is easy to prove that the distinction between these two (in a multiline command) things inside readline/bash **cannot be performed**.  And since the distinction cannot be performed there can not be keybindings for each.

Everything below assumes `set -o vi`

Let us say that I type the following in a bash prompt (I also press <kbd>Return</kbd> and the output is generated):

```
[~]$ echo "yay
> yep
> yup"
yay
yep
yup
```

Next I press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>k</kbd> and get the following (`{.}` is the location of the cursor):

```
[~]$ {e}cho "yay
yep
yup"
```

Note a couple of things:

1. `PS2` (`>` on my machine) was not printed as when I typed it directly.
2. If I keep pressing <kbd>k</kbd> and/or <kbd>j</kbd> I scroll through previous commands, not lines in command.

Therefore let's make a hypothesis that we are actually editing *not several lines* but a *single line which contains newline characters* (Yes, there is a huge difference there.  The command history (in memory) is stored as a linked list, not as text separated by newlines.).

And let's try to find a way to prove that the line becomes several commands only when the interpreter parses it.  Here is a command from the readline section of `man bash`:

```
comment-begin (``#'')
              The  string that is inserted when the readline insert-comment command is executed.  This command is bound to
              M-# in emacs mode and to # in vi command mode.
```

Basically, if we hit <kbd>#</kbd> the line should be commented out and passed to the interpreter (not sure why it is passed to the interpreter, to appear in the history I guess).  Anyhow, we know that, if we hit <kbd>#</kbd> a readline command will execute, i.e. it is not an editing biding (which should actually be "search next" in Vi).

Let's first more the cursor to the end by pressing <kbd>$</kbd>:

```
[~]$ echo "yay
yep
yup{"}
```

And now we hit <kbd>#</kbd>, things happen, and this is how the shell session looks:

```
[~]$ #echo "yay
yep
yup"
bash: yep: command not found
> { }
```

That seems strange, right?  But it is exactly what we asked, readline commented **the line** and passed it to the parser.  `echo "yay` got commented out, the shell attempted to run `yep` and we see `PS2` because we have an unfinished quote from `yup"`.  Type <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>Return</kbd> to get out.

So, what we can conclude is that **readline does not distinguish between the lines in the multiline command** we did input above.  If readline does not make a distinction then the Vi mode, which is on top of it, can't make the distinction either.

If you need to edit multiple lines separately from each other follow @BartonChittenden's answer (+1) and enter the editor.  An editor separates lines into different entities, so you can navigate between them.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence `Shift ^` seems to work for me.

Comment: That doesn't work, check out the updated copy of the question.

Comment: Using gnome terminal, screen and bash, and following your instructions, I'm not able to navigate at all (in vim's command mode), unless I first press `v` and then `Shift ^` works fine.  Can you describe what you actually see.

Comment: This isn't vim. This is bash with vim keybindings.

Comment: `s/vim's/vi's/` I'm aware that you're talking about readline's vi-like edit mode!

Comment: What Shift+^ does depends on the keyboard layout. For example, on a US layout, ^ is Shift+6. What character does Shift+^ produce on your keyboard?